# running class main via Jenkins Pipline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i want to run a maven project in jenkins (Pipline)

this is my simple class-main project:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("this is my main");
    }
}
```

i added it to Jenkins by giving the GitLab project link.

running sh 'mvn clean deploy' show me that the job is skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/create_pass_criteria/src/test/resources

**where do i need to specify to run the class main ?**
my class main is in the "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/create_pass_criteria/src/" directory, but the job keeps looking for "test/resources" directory.

this is my pom.xml if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>create_pass_criteria</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.imp.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporting</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.imp.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>sec-services</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.125-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.imp.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>systemtests-services</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.imp.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>systemtests-sec</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.125-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <mainClass>Create_pass_criteria.Main</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>arg0</argument>
                            <argument>arg1</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <name>release repo</name>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>scp:\\C:\\work\myfolder</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <name>snapshots repo</name>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>file:///C:/work/myfolder</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you explain why you like to run a main class? What is the purpose of doing so?

Comment: I have a project that is supposed to add tests to another project. so i need to run my project by class main. @khmarbaise

Comment: That project design sounds wrong. Tests should never be run via main method. Use unit tests for that...Furthermore a unit test should be only in the test area `src/test/java` and never being part of productive code...

Comment: i don't have tests. this is just a script, can i use Jenkins to run a script? @khmarbaise

Comment: First not having unit tests is an issue in itself...second what kind of purpose is your script? And why do you need it for a java project? Technically you can ran a script in Jenkins but the question is why do you need that script?

Comment: I think it would better to ask a question like "I want to add test cases automatically in such a way and for so and so purpose". There may be better solutions than compiling and running a Java program.